# nil object in iOS8 delegate methods - custom keyboards

Tags: ios, ios8, delegates, ios-app-extension

I'm building a custom keyboard 
and I'm implementing the following delegate methods in my `InputViewController`.
But I always get `_textInput = nil_`

```
- (void)textWillChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput
- (void)textDidChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput
- (void) selectionWillChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput
- (void) selectionDidChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?
Is it `nil` for a reason?
Do I need to implement something by myself?

Comment: Apple's API only mentions _"textInput The document instance whose class adopts the UITextInput protocol."_ Not exactly helpful. Does Apple have any sample code for this? There's way too much mist around this.

Comment: Now with beta 6, any call on `textInput` cause keyboard to crash.

Comment: @bauerMusic are you calling self.textDocumentProxy ? Which textInput do you mean?

Comment: The instance passed to `textDidChange:` delegate. Considering your original post, I'm also waiting to get some answers as to _what is_ this `id<UITextInput>` instance. Apple only note: _The document instance whose class adopts the UITextInput protocol._. Yet, it was nil and now calling it or trying to print it or even access it, cause the keyboard to crash.

Comment: @bauerMusic I guess it crashes because it is nil, no?

Comment: I think so. It crash when _checking_ for nil.

Comment: I have same problem. Was it solved?

Comment: @nurne Were you able to change your code to make this work? I added an answer for you last week.

Comment: Could you add the complete InputViewController code?

Answer (score 3):

Good question. But it seems that `UITextInputDelegate` is not a protocol that *you* implement.

From Apple Docs titled [Lower Level Text-Handling Technologies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/LowerLevelText-HandlingTechnologies/LowerLevelText-HandlingTechnologies.html):

> When changes occur in the text view due to external reasons—that is,
>   they aren't caused by calls from the text input system—the `UITextInput`
>   object should send `textWillChange:`, `textDidChange:`,
>   `selectionWillChange:`, and `selectionDidChange:` messages to the input
>   delegate (which it holds a reference to). For example, when users tap
>   a text view and you set the range of selected text to place the
>   insertion point under the finger, you would send `selectionWillChange:`
>   before you change the selected range, and you send `selectionDidChange:`
>   after you change the range.

And from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextInputDelegate/textWillChange:) on UITextInputDelegate:

> The UIKit provides a private text input delegate, which it assigns at
>   runtime to the inputDelegate property of the object whose class adopts
>   the UITextInput protocol.

The implication of the above is that we **don't implement** these delegate methods; we use them to inform the `inputDelegate` that you have changed your text or selection via means other than keyboard input.

Here is an [example](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/68050187/#l-2098) method that illustrates this:

```
- (void)delete:(id)sender;
{
    if (selection && ![selection isEmpty]) {
        [inputDelegate textWillChange:self];
        [inputDelegate selectionWillChange:self];
        [self replaceRange:selection withText:@""];
        [inputDelegate selectionDidChange:self];
        [inputDelegate textDidChange:self];
    }
}
```

Sample code with more examples [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/68050187/#l-2098).