# Custom Keyboard: get text from input view

Tags: iphone, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

i have developed a custom keyboard app of iOS8. and i can't get the text from input view. any help will be appreciated .
 have tried to use

```
 - (void)textDidChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput {}
```

delegate to get text. but it returns null value. i don't have another idea from which i can get text from input view 
thanks in advance

Comment: Some code will appreciate too

Comment: i have tried to use - (void)textDidChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput {} delegate to get text. but it returns null value. i don't have another idea from which i can get text from input view

Comment: i have no idea what does mean "input view" ? Is it text view, or text field, or something else ? Don't be shy to give us full description

Comment: i am able to get string from input view of custom keyboard of iOS 8 . here is the line of code which will return the string NSString *str=[self.textDocumentProxy documentContextBeforeInput]; thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596272/nil-object-in-ios8-delegate-methods-custom-keyboards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am able to get string from input view of custom keyboard of iOS 8 . here is the line of code which will return the string

```
    NSString *strBeforeCursor=[self.textDocumentProxy documentContextBeforeInput]; 
    NSString *strAfterCursor=[self.textDocumentProxy documentContextAfterInput];
```

thanks

Comment: it doesn't return the whole string, take a look:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479889/get-full-string-in-ios8-custom-keyboard-extension